# C++ Class instantiating and calling method within

Tags: c++, methods, instantiation

Alright, I just thought give C++ a try (I currently do C#), now my first problem is class instantiating or calling a method in another class.

Here is my code:
My main Program entry:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass.h"
using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        myClass* mc = new myClass();
    }
```

The Class I'm trying to access:

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass()
{
    void DoSomething();
    {

    }
}
myClass::~myClass()
{
}
```

The Class Header:

```
#pragma once
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
};
```

Now as you can see i have instantiated the class, but i cant access DoSomething() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code simply declares a local function, and has an empty scope for fun:

```
myClass::myClass()
{
    void DoSomething(); // local function declaration

    {
      // empty scope    
    }
}
```

If you want `doSomething()` to be a member of `myclass`, you have to declare it in the class definition:

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    void doSomething();
};
```

then implement it

```
void myclass::doSomething() { .... }
```

Also note that you don't have to use `new` everywhere in C++. You can instantiate an object like this:

```
int main()
{
    myClass mc;
}
```

Also note that [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) isn't such a great idea anyway, at least not in real code.

Comment: He does not even need the namespace since he is not using anything of it.

Answer (score 2):

this is a function declaration in a constructor (+an ampty scope within { }).

```
myClass::myClass()
{
    void DoSomething();
    {

    }
}
```

You want a function declaration in class body (not in constructor) and definition of this function (this can be done immediately together with declaration or later as i.e. here):

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass();
    ~myClass();
    void doSomething();
};
```

implementation of constructor:

```
myClass::myClass() { .... }
```

implementation of your function, similarly:

```
void myClass::doSomething() { .... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you are trying to use in main must be part of the class definition. You can write an inline function or can have a separate definition of that function. Also, you need to make that function public in order to access it from main.